Mix of Gaussian laws and Cauchy laws
Let

$n \in \mathbb{N}$
$X_1 ... X_n$ are independent and follow a gaussian law $\mathcal{N}( m, \sigma^2)$
$Y_1 ... Y_n$ are independent and follow a gaussian law $\mathcal{N}( m, \sigma^2)$
$(X_i)_i$ and $(Y_i)_i$ are independent
$T_n =\frac{|\bar{X_n} -m |}{|\bar{Y_n} -m |}$
$U_n= \mathbb{1}_{T_n<1}$
$Z_n= U_n\bar{X_n}+(1-U_n)\bar{Y_n}$
$W_n= \sqrt{n}(Z_n-m)$
$A_n= \sqrt{n} (\bar{X_n} -m )$
$B_n= \sqrt{n} (\bar{Y_n} -m )$
We notice that $W_n$ can be rewritten as $W_n= A_n \mathbb{1}_{ |A_n| <|B_n|} + B_n \mathbb{1}_{ |B_n| <|A_n|}$

We want to express $P(W_n <w)$ for $w \in \mathbb{R}$ with $H$ the cumulative function of a standard gaussian law and $h$ the density of a standard gaussian law.
What is the limit law of $W_n$ ?

I have proved some intermediary results.

if $Z$ is a standard Cauchy law, the density of $|Z|$, $f_{|Z|}(t)=\frac{2}{\pi (1+t²)}$
$f_{Z²}(t)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \frac{1}{1+t}$
$T_n$ converges in law to the law of $|Z|$ with the central limit theorem
$P(T_n<1) \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ so $U_n$ converges in law to a Bernoulli law of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$
$Z_n$ converges in law to the constant $m$

For the main question
$P(W_n <w)=P( A_n <w, |A_n| <|B_n|) + P( B_n <w, |B_n| <|A_n|)= 2 P( A_n <w, |A_n| <|B_n|)$ by symmetry. And $\{A_n<w,  |A_n| <|B_n| \}= \{- |B_n| < A_n < \min ( |B_n|,w) \}$
So $P(W_n<w) = 2 \int_{b \in \mathbb{R}} [ F_n( |b|,w)) - F_n (|b|)] f_n(b) db$
where $F_n$ is the common cumulative function of $A_n$ and $B_n$ and $f_n$ is the common density of $A_n$ and $B_n$.
